# How to pass a value on selected row change?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I have this permanent problem, I have a Datatable with `value="#{myBean.Items}" var="itms"`, and I want to pass the selected item to my bean class.

In columns, we use `<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{itms}" target="#{myBean.selectedrow}" />` to pass the value, but I want it for Rows.
How to do that?, and where to put this listener?.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Doesn't a single `itms` identify the content of the entire row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What richface version are you using?

For richfaces 4.3.x, the following example might do the trick:

**XHTML:**

```
<rich:extendedDataTable
  id="myTable"
  value="#{crudBean.rows}"
  var="rowItem"
  rowClasses="odd-row, even-row"
  selection="#{crudBean.actionForm.selection}"
  rows="#{crudBean.actionForm.occurrences}"
  rowKeyVar="idx"
>
  <a4j:ajax event="selectionchange"
    listener="#{crudBean.actionForm.selectionListener}"
    immediate="true" />
  <rich:column width="100px" styleClass="#{rowItem.className}">
    ...stuff...
  </rich:column>
  <rich:column width="173px" styleClass="#{rowItem.className}">
    ...stuff...
  </rich:column>
</rich:extendedDataTable>
```

The following code made sure the even got fired on row selection change:

```
<a4j:ajax event="selectionchange"
  listener="#{crudBean.actionForm.selectionListener}"
  immediate="true" />
```

**The bean:**

```
public void selectionListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
  UIExtendedDataTable currentDataTable = (UIExtendedDataTable) event.getComponent();
  Object originalKey = currentDataTable.getRowKey();

  // debug log statement
  log.debug("selectionListener() - rowKey = {} ", originalKey);
  // debug log statement
  if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
    log.debug("\n selectionListener() - rowIndex = {}", currentDataTable.getRowIndex());
  }
  if (currentDataTable.isRowAvailable()) {
    // selectionItems.add(dataTable.getRowData());
    IDataRow rowValue = transform((IDataGridRow)currentDataTable.getRowData());
    changeActiveRow(rowValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, just to get the idea, please update your answer to clarify the following: 1-) In selectionListener code in my Bean, how can I use the value of idx. 2-) What are occurrences and selection properties. Thanks.

Comment: on the bean side you dont use idx, but the selected row (number). Selection of the row is the trigger to what i listen for action (mouseclick on a row or going down/up with keyboard)